# Create Marker but not show it on the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I would like to know how I can create a Marker but not to show on the map, I'm saving the Markers in an array but it is showing me on the map, this is my code

```
if (c4!= null ) {
            if  (c4.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {                                   
                LatLng posicion = new LatLng(
                    Double.parseDouble(c4.getString(0)),
                    Double.parseDouble(c4.getString(1)));

                        punto = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() .position(posicion)
                                .title(c4.getString(2))
                                .snippet(year)
                                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));

                        mMarkers.add(punto);

                            }while (c4.moveToNext());
                       }
            }
```

I've tried and used this

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
```

but this does not work for me as I need to be type Marker.

Anyone know how could i save spots without paint on the map? thank you very much and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: So you are telling that you should save this marker in array ?

Comment: That's right!, what happens is that I save it and show it to me, and I just want to keep

Comment: See the answer below it might help you

Comment: have you tried .visible(false) or setVisible(false)?

Comment: if I put the invisible is going print on Map

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
punto = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() .position(posicion)
                            .title(c4.getString(2))
                            .snippet(year)
                            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f).visible(false));
```

instead of

```
punto = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() .position(posicion)
                            .title(c4.getString(2))
                            .snippet(year)
                            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Notice the `.visible(false)` part.

For further info regarding the same refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

save the markers in this list

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
markers.add(marker); // here the marker is of google map
```

Then afterwords use Clear() on your google map so that the markers that got add should be deleted

EDIT=
Also you can separately remove a single marker by

```
marker.remove();
```

you can also try to save the latitude and longitude in array list and then later as you like it, show them through marker.

Comment: but then the only way is to clean the paint not map every time you add?

Comment: Please Explain Clean the Paint ?.. also the above will clear the markers from the map after saving it to the list.

Comment: the only way is not to paint the Markers is with google.clean (); ?

Comment: you can also try to save the latitude and longitude in array list and then later as you like it, show them through marker. Is it necessary to make marker rather then save the lats and longs in array list ?

Comment: I will try to keep the lat and lng thank you very much for everything